# Cellar clustering in servicemix

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Installed cellar in 2 ServiceMix in 2 different PCs using following commands.

```
features:addurl mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-cellar/2.3.4/xml/features

features:install cellar
```

Made IP address of node 2 entry in `<tcp-ip>` tag of `hazelcast.xml` in node 1

I Started servicemix in PC 1 : Node 1
  Started servicemix in PC 2 : Node 2

Checked the clustering discovery using `cluster:node-list` in both the nodes. Both lists both the Node 1 and Node 2.

I do not know how to test this clustering.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do here ... a bit more input is required. In the meantime take a look at the tests of cellar itself. Might already what you are asking for.

Comment: I tried creating servicemix instances in my pc and deployed same bundle in both the servicemix. installed cellar in both. My bundle contains a simple file transfer route. At first on copying 1 file into the input folder its transfered to destination using Node 1. If i stop Node 1 and do the same transfer(failover case), Node 2 transfers the file. This is working fine. Now i want to create servicemix clusters in 2 different machines. Can anyone help me how to configure this??

Comment: Please clarify your question above ... what are you trying to do?
Usually a cellar cluster does have an auto discovery for other nodes.

Comment: Yes it auto discovers the other cellar nodes making use of multicast feature in hazelcast. This works inside single pc. My question is regarding discovery of cellar nodes in 2 different pcs.

Comment: Same thing, auto discovery works within the same network as it uses multicast. Make sure A your network device supports this B your two nodes reside in the same subnet, or C make sure you define the correct subnet in the hazelcast.xml.

Comment: Nope Its not working. If its in different system hazelcast should be told to find cellar nodes in that system. hence we specify the ipaddress. I specified working system ip address in interface tag and another system Ip in hostname tag. Likewise same i did in other system. It worked and when i run "cluster:node-list" command in karaf, It shows both the nodes. But when i run "cluster:node-ping <hostname>:<port> of the other system it shows time out message, not getting any reply. I feel like im almost there, What else did i miss??